# Question about pistons and how their volume is affected by particles?

Tags: pressure, work, volume

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. When pressure is maintained in a piston and an ideal gas is injected into it (again, with no change in pressure as it is injected) the piston is displaced upwards. Does the composition of the gas beyond the quantity of particles affect the displacement? As in, will heavier particles cause greater (or smaller) displacement on the piston as compared to the same amount of lighter particles? Do the heavier particles perform more (or less) work than the same amount of lighter particles? Or does this have nothing to do with the change in displacement of the piston?

Thanks!!

Comment: is your question about piston engines? i.e. car engines?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer lies in the ideal gas law:
$$PV = nRT$$
where $P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume, $n$ is the amount of substance (usually in moles), $R$ is the "ideal gas" constant, and $T$ is temperature.  You can see from the equation that if you're adding  substance (i.e. increasing $n$), $V$ must increase proportionally (i.e. the piston must be displaced) to maintain constant pressure.  Additionally, there is no dependence on the weight of the particles.  One mole of hydrogen in a 1L volume at a given temperature produces the same pressure as 1 mole of oxygen in the same volume at the same temperature; the litre of hydrogen just weighs less.